# applying Lob theorem

Tags: logic

For the understanding Lob theorem, I want show an example.

Let followings be some famous theorems in mathematics academia for a theory T. They are already proven decades ago.

> Theorem 1: if F, then A → B
>
> Theorem 2:  (if T ⊢ ( A → B ) ) then (  C  → E  )
>
> Theorem 3:  if (  C  → E  ), then F

Someday, one person found a fact accidentally that

( Theorem 2 and 3 and 1 ) ⊢ { ( if T ⊢ ( A → B ), then ( A → B )  }

We already know that Theorem 1, 2, 3 is provable sentence in theory T. So,

This person insists that by this fact, T ⊢  ( A → B ) by Lob theorem.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but if you're trying to use Löb's theorem to resolve a major unsolved problem, then I bet you that one or more of the steps you've just written down is wrong.